# Making divs have different mouse over affects

Tags: javascript, slider

i am new to JS and need some help please!

I have 2 Boxes(divs) that have a slider in each one. When I mouse over anyone of them, both sliders are activated.

How would i make it so each div is activated separately.

here are my pictures of what I am doing, might make it a little more clear:

pic.twitter.com/1ju3iZ0KIM - before mouse over
pic.twitter.com/gmfhl1zl2J - with mouse over

Thanks so much!

This is my JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
            $('.default').stop().animate({
                height: 0  
            }, 200);                        
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.default').stop().animate({
                height: 170 
            }, 200)    
        })
    });
</script>
```

my divs

```
<div class="squareFeedBox">
    <div class="up-down">
        <div class="slide default"></div>
        <div class="slide onhover"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="squareFeedBox">
    <div class="up-down">
        <div class="slide default"></div>
        <div class="slide onhover"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css

/*Content Boxes*/

```
.squareFeedBox
{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 278.5px;
    height: 207px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #0f2134;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*upSlider*/

.up-down 
{
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 207px;
    width: 278.5px;
}

.slide 
{
    width:278.5px;
    height:207px;
}



.default 
{
    background-color:#fff;
    height: 170px;
    width: 278.5px;
}

.onhover 
{
    background-color:#1DB7CB;
    height: 207px;
    width: 278.5px;  
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `onMouseOver` event?  Also, make sure the divisions in question have unique names and IDs.

Comment: And not same class name.

Comment: Please try to identify a problem area in your solution and post the relevant code so that we can help.

Comment: sorry - I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Add "this" keyword and optionaly replace $(document).ready(function(...)) on $(function(...)).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
            $('.default', this).stop().animate({
                          ^^^^
                height: 0  
            }, 200);                        
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.default', this).stop().animate({
                          ^^^^
                height: 170 
            }, 200)    
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what i put in next?

Comment: You should add "this" keyword and optionaly replace $(document).ready(function(...)) on $(function(...)). That's it :)

Comment: The keyword "this" shows that you are looking for '.default' inside the current '.up-down' element.

Comment: @user1754324 If this answer solved your problem, please come back and mark it as the accepted answer.